# Is a meta-sodium sulfonate group on a benzene ring electron withdrawing or donating?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I am wondering if a sodium sulfinate group would decrease or increase the electron density of the aromatic ring

Comment: I'd say it is like carboxylate group, only worse.

Comment: I agree, the S is strongly d positive and that will draw electron density out of the ring.

Comment: Related: [Directing nature of the -SOR substituent in electrophilic aromatic substitution](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/93518)

Comment: @Gaurang not related.  Adding another oxygen atom changes a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

As $\ce{SO3H}$ is a strongly electron withdrawing group, I'd say that $\ce{SO3Na}$ is basically the same, but to a slightly less extent. The reason for this is that being a group of highly electronegative atoms both groups have strong inductive electron withdrawing effects but they are both at donating electrons via conjugation (only possible from $\ce{S\bond{2}O}$ bond). This means that the sodium sulfonate group will decrease the electron density on the aromatic ring.